# Mongoose updating a reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here I have 2 schemas:

User:

```
User = {
   name: String,
   office: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Office'
   }
}
```

Office:

```
Office = {
   name: String
}


Office.virtual('employees', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'office',
    justOne: false
});
```

When I try to update Office.employees, I can't update User.office by the reference, how can I do that?

For updating I use:

```
 Office.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {employees: ['id of employee']})
```

Comment: what's your code for updating?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, edited

Comment: which version of MongoDB are you running?

Comment: it is version 5.0.3

Comment: have you tried [this link here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) cause I don't think your query is correct.